# dominated convergence theorem in d dimension in L^p

Tags: real-analysis, probability, probability-theory, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-differential-equations

I am reading the book *STOCHASTIC DIFFERENTIAL EQUATIONS AND APPLICATIONS* wrote by prof.Mao. In page 6, there is a dominated convergence theorem in d dimension in $L^p$, which seems different from the other dominated convergence theorem I read in other books. It states like this:

[dominated convergence theorem in d dimension in $L^p$](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jYoSz.png)

I am confused what is the "$|X_k|$" here mean? Is it a Euclidean norm operator? Because this transform a random variable in $R^d$ to $R$. What is it exact format? Some people told me that after $|\cdot|$ operator, it becomes a real number? Why? Is he true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the condition they are stating is: $\mu(\{\omega \in \Omega: ||X_k(\omega)||_1 \leq Y(\omega)\}) = 1$

where $||.||_1$ is $L_1$ norm. Now we can directly apply the $1$-dimensional dominated convergence theorem since every component of $|X_k|$ is now bounded by $|Y|$ and the premise of 1-dimensional dominated convergence theorem holds. We can now apply limit to each component of $X_k$ and conclude the theorem.

The above is true. You can actually put other norms also $||X_k(\omega)||_{\ell}$ also works since all norms are equivalent in finite dimensional case $d < \infty$ i.e., $||X_k(\omega)||_1 \leq C(d) \times ||X_k(\omega)||_{\ell}$.

So the statement is true for all $p$ norms.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So, in $L_1$ norm, $|X_k| = |X_1| + |X_2| \cdots |X_d|$ right? It still a random variable? Or a real number?

Comment: At a particular $\omega \in \Omega$, $||X_k(\omega)||_1 = |X_1(\omega)| + |X_2(\omega)|+...+|X_d(\omega)|$ is a real number. A random variable is just a measurable function. So no difference. The only difference between a normal measurable function and a random variable is the measure over which we integrate.

Comment: Sorry, I am confused again. What is the definition of $|\cdot|$ to a random variable? Here, without specifying $\omega$ in advance, then $||X_k||_1 = |X_1| + |X_2|+...+|X_d|$, it seems that $X_1, X_2, \cdots, X_d$ are all still random variable, right? So what is the definition of $|X_i|, i \in \{1, 2, \cdots, d\}$?

Comment: You can think of $||X_k||_1 = |X_1| + |X_2| + .... + |X_d|$ as a random variable. But random variable by definition is a measurable function from $\Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{\ell}$ for some $\ell$. So saying $||X_k||_1 \leq Y$ means  $||X_k||_1 \leq Y$ as a measurable function with this inequality holding almost surely or $||X_k||_1 \leq Y$ is a probability $1$ event as a random variable. Both views are one and the same.

Comment: $X_k(\omega) = [X_1(\omega),....,X_d(\omega)]$ is a vector for each $\omega \in \Omega$.

Comment: $Probability(\{\omega \in \Omega: ||X_k (\omega)||_1 = |X_1(\omega)| + ... + |X_d(\omega)| \leq Y(\omega)\}) = 1$

Comment: oh, I think I am a little bit understandable. It means for almost all $\omega$, $||X_k(\omega)||_1 = |X_1(\omega)| + |X_2(\omega)|+...+|X_d(\omega)| \leq Y(\omega)$, here, $|X_1(\omega)|$ is a real number, so it is just the definition of real number(eg.|-1| = |1| = 1). $||X_k(\omega)||_1 = |X_1(\omega)| + |X_2(\omega)|+...+|X_d(\omega)| \leq Y(\omega)$ then follows the rule of comparing between real number, right?

Comment: yes correct. When u say for almost all $\omega$, it means probability of such $\omega$ is $1$.

Comment: got it, many thanks to you!